# How to add to Hbase classpath?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-phoenix

I am trying to install a custom version on phoenix on my hbase cluster. I have 1 master and 2 slave nodes. If I do `yum install phoenix` it installs version `4.7.0`. I am interested in installing version `4.10.0`. I am following the extremely short instructions given here - https://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html . However in step 2 it says :

> Add the phoenix-[version]-server.jar to the classpath of all HBase
>   region server and master and remove any previous version. An easy way
>   to do this is to copy it into the HBase lib directory (use
>   phoenix-core-[version].jar for Phoenix 3.x)

How do I go about doing this? There is no verison on phoenix in the `hadoop-env.sh`. I dont see any environment variables setup for hadoop when I do `printenv`. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How was Hbase installed?

Comment: `yum install hbase`

Comment: Then copy the jar to `/usr/lib/hbase/lib/`.

Comment: I just copied it to that path in mater and slave nodes and restarted hbase in all 3 machines

Comment: Unsure. Keep running into `Wed Apr 05 19:48:48 UTC 2017, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@5a4bef8, java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: hii.. can i ask you how do you solve this problem?? Thanks!!